# Jquery not working in child page if master page has lightbox js files

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

To get lightbox functionality in my page,i have added js files in master page.
after some time,i needed to use jquery in child page.so i have added jquery reference in child page.
When i added jquery reference in child page,lightbox stops working.

How to resolve this problem?
when i remove jquery reference from child page,lightbox works fine.
Is this Jquery conflict problem??

FYI i have shown my js files here

Master Page Javascript files :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lightbox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/lightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Child page Javascript files :

```
<script src="../js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">     </script> 

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var $j = jQuery.noConflict(true);

        function showClose(obj) {            
            obj.style.display = 'none';
            $j("#spnFullInfo").slideDown(1500);           
            return false;
        }
</script>
```

Comment: "not working" can you provide more details? error message or something

Comment: which lightbox is it? jquery lightbox or something else?

Comment: i have downloaded Lightbox from http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/ . "not working"means image opens in window instead of popup div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try first only lightbox functionality. Keep only jquery.js and lightbox.js remove other .js files. you might have conflict with prototype or scriptaculuos.

Comment: @Rohit.. i know there is conflict between js files but i want to resolve that conflict..how?

Comment: Lightbox from lokeshdhakar does not require jquery . I uses prototype , which is just like jquery.you can use following to resolve conflicts between them.


<script>
     jQuery.noConflict();
     
     // Use jQuery via jQuery(...)  && prototype library will use $(...)
    
        function showClose(obj) {            
            obj.style.display = 'none';
            jQuery("#spnFullInfo").slideDown(1500);           
            return false;
        }
   </script>

Answer (score 0):

Just put your jquery reference in master page instead of child.

Hope this helps..